# Why does xpath.each return an element instead of a node?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'd like to iterate the results of an `xpath` search, so I can do stuff with the nodes. Nokogiri's docs and examples say that `xpath` returns a NodeSet and `NodeSet.each` returns a Node, which is what I want however I am getting an Element. What have I done wrong?

This simplified code highlights the issue. There are many related questions on StackOverflow, although they are domain specific, obscuring the issue, and no exact match to this question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root xmlns="http://example.org/1">

  <item>
    <value>One</value>
  </item>

  <item>
    <value>Two</value>
  </item>
</root>
```

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'nokogiri'

xmlfile = File.open("testfile.xml")
xmldoc = Nokogiri::XML(xmlfile)

xmldoc.xpath("//xmlns:value").each do |node|
    if (node.nil?) then
        next
    end
    puts "node is a #{node.class}"
end
```

```
node is a Nokogiri::XML::Element
node is a Nokogiri::XML::Element
```

Comment: An `Element` **is** a `Node`. (Not every `Node` is an `Element`.) Imagine "I went to a pet store to get some animals, but they sold me _kittens_, not animals!"

Comment: https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Element.html

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't do Nodey things on my Element like .parent, but your clarification confirms it must be other bugs in my code.  Would you like to convert your comment to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converted from comments per request:

An `Element` **is** a `Node`. (Not every `Node` is an `Element`.)

```
# is Element a kind of a Node?
Nokogiri::XML::Element < Nokogiri::XML::Node
# => true

# is every node I get from xpath a Node?
xmldoc.xpath("//xmlns:value").all? { |node| node.is_a?(Nokogiri::XML::Node) }
# => true

# can I get a parent from each node I get from xpath?
xmldoc.xpath("//xmlns:value").map { |node| node.parent.name }
# => ["item", "item"]
```

Answer (score 3):

This might help clarify what's happening:

```
require 'nokogiri'

types = {
  1 => 'ELEMENT_NODE',
  2 => 'ATTRIBUTE_NODE',
  3 => 'TEXT_NODE',
  4 => 'CDATA_SECTION_NODE',
  5 => 'ENTITY_REF_NODE',
  6 => 'ENTITY_NODE',
  7 => 'PI_NODE',
  8 => 'COMMENT_NODE',
  9 => 'DOCUMENT_NODE',
  10 => 'DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE',
  11 => 'DOCUMENT_FRAG_NODE',
  12 => 'NOTATION_NODE',
  13 => 'HTML_DOCUMENT_NODE',
  14 => 'DTD_NODE',
  15 => 'ELEMENT_DECL',
  16 => 'ATTRIBUTE_DECL',
  17 => 'ENTITY_DECL',
  18 => 'NAMESPACE_DECL',
  19 => 'XINCLUDE_START',
  20 => 'XINCLUDE_END',
  21 => 'DOCB_DOCUMENT_NODE',
}

doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(<<EOT)
<xml>
  <t1>foo</t1>
  bar
</xml>
EOT

doc.xpath('//.').each do |n|
  puts "'%s' is a %s containing \"%s\"" % [n.name, types[n.type], n.content]
end
```

Which results in:

```
# >> 'document' is a DOCUMENT_NODE containing "
# >>   foo
# >>   bar
# >> "
# >> 'xml' is a ELEMENT_NODE containing "
# >>   foo
# >>   bar
# >> "
# >> 'text' is a TEXT_NODE containing "
# >>   "
# >> 't1' is a ELEMENT_NODE containing "foo"
# >> 'text' is a TEXT_NODE containing "foo"
# >> 'text' is a TEXT_NODE containing "
# >>   bar
# >> "
```

A parser like [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org), which lives under Nokogiri, breaks down the XML or HTML into a variety of different types of nodes, and that is then passed back to Nokogiri.

Depending on the search accessor, you could get any of the various types but usually the most usable are the tags in the document:

```
doc.xpath('//t1').each do |n|
  puts "'%s' is a %s containing \"%s\"" % [n.name, types[n.type], n.content]
end
# >> 't1' is a ELEMENT_NODE containing "foo"
```

With those we can search or navigate the document finding nodes of interest, find and extract their content or isolate sections and move, alter or delete them, or insert new content.

Occasionally we care about the text nodes because we want intervening text or to mangle the formatting:

```
doc.xpath('//text()').each do |n|
  puts "'%s' is a %s containing %s" % [n.name, types[n.type], n.content.inspect]
end
# >> 'text' is a TEXT_NODE containing "\n  "
# >> 'text' is a TEXT_NODE containing "foo"
# >> 'text' is a TEXT_NODE containing "\n  bar\n"
```

That might help 'splain what you're seeing and pique your curiosity about what else is under the hood.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Your contribution should find a place in the sparse  Nokogiri [docs](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet).

Comment: The docs are pretty good, but they're very much oriented to experienced Ruby programmers. The tutorials and cheat-sheet are also, so it makes it difficult for beginners just learning how to deal with parsers and searching XML/HTML. I started with much more primitive ones then migrated to Ruby's early on, so to me it wasn't a big step, just a lot more robust.